# Creating a shared ilbrary app with wxWidgets (with pthreads)

Tags: c++, dll, pthreads, shared-libraries, wxwidgets

I want to create an wxWidgets app that is loaded from a shared library. It should be added as a plugin to an already existing C application.

In the samples directory (/samples/dll) of wxWidgets i found the file "my_dll.cpp". It's  exactly what i need. It is exclusively for windows though. I need to make a .so linux version of it.

So i rewrote everything winapi thread related with pthreads. I have never really done multithreading so there are probably lots of mistakes in the code but i am not able to find them.

Maybe someone can help.

the most relevant functions are:

`void run_wx_gui_from_dll(const char *title)`

and

`void* MyAppLauncher(void* event)`

here is a link to the samples file from wxWidgets that uses winapi threads http://pastebin.com/KhK4uiKZ
here is a link to the code that uses pthreads http://pastebin.com/QmsPqYs5

My pthread version only works correctly when i put a sleep at the end of `run_wx_gui_from_dll`.

Without the sleep `CMD_SHOW_WINDOW` won't open a new frame. Just nothing happens. I put `puts("received show window command");` in `void MyDllApp::OnShowWindow`. The string is printed to stdout so i know that wxQueueEvent works.
But wxWidgets seems to block at `wxFrame *f = new MyDllFrame`

```
  ...
  ...
  // Send a message to wx thread to show a new frame:
  wxThreadEvent *event =
  new wxThreadEvent(wxEVT_THREAD, CMD_SHOW_WINDOW);
  event->SetString(title);
  wxQueueEvent(wxApp::GetInstance(), event);

  sleep(3);
}
```

The windows version does not need a sleep.

`run_wx_gui_from_dll` starts a new thread from which the wxWidgets event loop is called. It then needs to wait until wxWidgets is properly initialized until it can queue commands. That is why i used the pthread condition. The windows version does a similar thing.

I also don't know what `wxCriticalSectionLocker` does. I left it in there just in case. Maybe that's part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One error I see in your code is that you must lock the mutex before launching the thread, otherwise it may signal its initialization before you started waiting for it. I'm not sure this explains your problem (in fact, it probably doesn't), but it would still be nice to fix it. And if the problem persists, I'm afraid you really need to debug it and see what's going on, i.e. which thread is doing what.

It's also definitively a pity that we can't just use `wxThread` here, it's pretty annoying to have to write platform-specific to initialize a platform-independent library. We really ought to add some `wxInitializeInNewThread()` or something like this... If, by chance, you'd be interested in contributing it, please don't hesitate to post to wx-dev mailing list.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the error. If i lock the the mutex before starting the thread i don't even need the pthread condition. It's much simpler now. The problem remains though.